# How to make regular expression to pass these conditions

Tags: ruby, regex

i want to make regular expression to validates length of a phone number with only two  condition.First it should be 10 in length.

the string should be 10 digits in length and can be any digits like

```
          4345623467
```

and if string is 11 in length then should be start with 1 like.

```
          14345623467
```

the length can be 10 or 11.Other length should not be valid

Thanks for any help.

Comment: make regex for above strings because i am very weak in regex

Comment: The way you get better at anything is by *trying*, not demanding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regular expression matches either a sequence of 10 or 11 digits starting with "1" or any sequence of exactly ten digits:

```ruby
/^(?:1\d{9,10}|\d{10})$/
```

Here is how it breaks down, so that you can become stronger with regular expressions:

```text
/^(?:1\d{9,10}|\d{10})$/
 │├─┘ ├──────┘ ├────┘ └ The end of the string.
 ││   │        └ Any digit repeated exactly ten times.
 ││   └ Any digit (0-9) repeated nine or ten times.
 │└ A non-matching group of two possible matches separated by a pipe (?:...|...)
 └ The start of the string.
```

Answer (score 5):

A simpler one: optional `1` followed by 10 digits

```
/^1?\d{10}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

That should do it:

```
/^(\d{10}|1\d{10})$/
```